# is there a way to stop server side streaming when client disconnected

Tags: java, grpc

here is pseudo code to impl a server side streaming:

```java
@Override
public void someMethod(XXRequest request,  StreamObserver<XXEvent> responseObserver) {
    try {
                while (!Context.current().isCancelled()) {
                    XXEvent event = heavyCompute();
                    if (event != null) {
                        responseObserver.onNext(event);
                    }
                }
    } finally {
           doClean();
    }
}
```

On client side, if everything is ok, CancellableContext.cancel() or ManagedChannel.shutdownNow() will terminate someMethod call gracefully, but if client crashes, someMethod call will run forever...

so is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.